# Extraction of the JSON Object from a JSON file using streams of JAVA 8

Tags: java, json, stream

I wish to extract a JSON object from a JSON file. The catch is that, I would like to get the nth json object which is inside another object. For simplicity, I would give an example. 
For better reference, I have attached my sample JSON here in.

```
    {
 "header": {
    "Company Name": "ABC",
    "Address": "XYZ",
    "Registration": "XYZq", 
  },  
  "data": [
    {
      "EmployeeNo": "254535",
      "DateHired": "2019-10-04",
      "personalDetails": 
      {
        "Father Name": "ABCD",
        "PhoneNumber": "7868868686",
        "pstlAdrress": {
          "Country": "India",
          "Town": "Mumbai"
                    }
       },
    }

  ]
}
```

From there, I wish to get the values of Country and Town in string format. How can I get the same. I wish to use the streams concept of JAVA 8 here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yeah I tried to extract the values first by passing the whole message into a JSON Object and then extracting individual data from the same by using getstring() function.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the InputStream, the FileReader and the Object mapper by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Here a method to get a plain JSON string from your resource:

```
public String getJsonFromResource(String resource) {
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(YOURCLASS.class.getResource(resource).getFile())) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            json.append(line);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json.toString();
}
```

And here the method to map the JSON as an object:

```
public YourObject getYourObject(String plainJson) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    YourObject yourObject = objectMapper.readValue(plainJson, YourObject.class);

    return yourObject;
}
```

//EDIT:

To get an object stored in a field in another object, you just need to create a java class with the specific fields. For example:

```
public class YourObject {

    private YourSecondObject yourSecondObject;

}
```

And the objectmapper should do everything automatically.

Comment: Pojo/Object should contain one more reference Pojo/object. Change code as per Mishra mentioned

Comment: Thanks for the input Lova. But the requirement is something like I need to get the values extracted from the inner most Object of the a JSON Object which has 2 parents above it..

Comment: @DebasishMishra if you only want to get the "inner inner" values, you could use JsonPath